# The way the past participle is used in these sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-participles, participles, gerund-vs-infinitive

First, this is the *meaning* I am trying to put in writing:

> She could not tolerate the sight of them **as they were being** put
>   to death.

And I want the progressive aspect to be clear.

Which of the following sentences express that meaning correctly, and most eloquently?

I.

> She could not tolerate the **sight of** them **put** to death.

II.

> She could not tolerate the **sight of** them **being put** to death.

III.

> She could not tolerate **seeing** them **be put** to death.

Thank you.

Comment: If the ongoing nature of the incident is important to you, why not double up on the progressive?  Thus:  "She could not tolerate seeing them being put to death."  "Be put" is not valid.

Comment: Thank you. And is "She could not tolerate the sight of them being put to death" *grammatically* valid?

Answer (score 0):

None of these appears ideal from a technical clarity perspective. Number three might be the closest to a good choice if changed to `She could not tolerate seeing their being put to death`. Number two could become `She could not tolerate the sight of their being put to death`. Although the usage is common, using an object ("them") modified by an adjectival clause ("being put to death") often leads to ambiguities. For example, in the sentence `They didn't like him being put to death`, the author is probably trying to convey that "they" didn't like the *action*, yet the sentence could technically be saying "they" didn't like the *person* that happened to be about to die. In fact, the "being put to death" could even be referring to "they" rather than the person being put to death. Using the possessive "their" or "his" solves this problem of clarity: `They didn't like his being put to death`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this difficulty arises for two reasons:

1. *The sight* implies a single instance of seeing, rather than a continuing experience.

   2. The verb *put* is similar, in that it occurs at a single instant of time. You cannot *put* something, and continue putting it over a period of time.

I think these two things combine to jar against your intended meaning, which is a *continuous* experience.

For this I would suggest the word *watching*, as that suggests a prolonged experience. If you were set on the three alternatives above, I would prefer the third, as at least *seeing* implies activity rather than a single instantaneous experience (*the sight*).

In terms of *put*, you could substitute either a specific means of death and frame it in an active sense, or simply substitute the verb *die* for a more dramatic and brusque impact.

So if you were willing to deviate from the original three, perhaps something like *she could not tolerate watching them drown*.

Substituting the specific means of death has the additional benefit of capturing the reader's empathy; if you hint at how they were put to death, the reader can imagine *why* the woman couldn't bear to look.